# How do I assign a worker to a resource object?

Tags: fallout-4

When building various structures such as the guard post or the scavenger workbench, you're prompted to assign a worker to the resource object:

[image: assign a worker prompt]

However... I'm not seeing any indication of how I'm meant to achieve this, and without assigning a worker the structure doesn't operate...

[image: worker required]

How do I assign a worker to a resource object?

Comment: Step 1: Send me your copy of Fallout. Step 2: There is no step 2.

Comment: [Is this of any help?](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s1s87/assign_worker_to_building/). Btw, step 1 is my address, not Studoku

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is actually not as difficult as originally thought, although it can be time consuming and isn't particularly intuitive - in order to assign a worker to a resource you must be in workshop mode and then approach the person you want to be the worker, speak to them and "command" them:

[image: command a villager]

...then go to the location you want them to work and you'll have the option to assign them to that post.

[image: select a resource object]

They'll then walk over from their original position and start working.