# What does a Scavenging Station do and how do I use it?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm at a loss here. I've built a Scavenging station and I assigned one of my settlers to it.

I can't seem to harvest anything from it, use it in any way or see the benefit of having one.

What is the purpose of this thing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can't do anything at a scavenging station personally; it has to be operated by an NPC.
From what I can surmise, you have to enter workshop mode, select a spare settler (when you have settlers, of course), and then assign that settler to work at the scavenging station. You also have to select the scavenging station, and assign it to be worked at by the settler.

Source: [This question posted earlier on Stack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242514/how-do-i-assign-a-worker-to-a-resource-object).

Each assigned scavenging station adds one random resource to your workshop inventory for every 8 in-game hours, for a total of 3 resources per game day. It may also respawn random resources near your settlement.

Source: [This post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3s9eyl/what_does_the_scavenging_station_do_and_how_do_i/).

Comment: Yes I already assigned a settler to it. My question is, for what purpose and how do I take advantage of having one?

Comment: I thought the settler assigned to the scavanger station does not look for random items, but tries to find items that you marked as 'required'?

Answer (score 12):

The Scavenging Station gives three random junk items daily. You may have to fast travel a great distance or rest a little more than 24 hours. I tested two Scav Stations at Abernathy Farms, took everything from the Workshop's inventory, and in less than 48 hours there was Fertilizer, Melon (2), Screw, Tato, and Typwriter. One Scav Station at Tenpines Bluff gave me Cloth, Corn, Gourd, and Purified Water. One settler was tending food at each location as well.

Comment: Which crops were growing at those locations? Did any excess crop show up in the workshop? *Were* their any excess crops? I'm asking because someone has reported their [scavenging station collecting excess crops](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245234/how-can-i-automate-my-crop-harvest?noredirect=1#comment338935_245234).

Comment: Yes, do you need a scav station in order for crops and purified water to show up in your supply cache? Or is it enough to just have the crops and water supply?

Answer (score 3):

The scavenging table will send one of your settlers out into the wasteland to search for loot. Anything they find and bring back will be put into your workbench inventory at that settlement