# How can I automate my crop harvest?

Tags: fallout-4

Is there any easier way to collect the fruit of my settlement crops without individually collecting the food myself? For instance, the extra purified water goes straight to the workshop.

Comment: Personally I wish I could just set up a plot of land for a type of crop and let the settlers deal with planting as well. That way we could also have irrigation and fertilizer playing a part as well

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe that crop harvest is already automated. Every time I return to Sanctuary, I can cook lots of Vegetable Starch, even though I'm pretty sure I only found at best 1 or 2 Tato and Corn each.

Comment: @Nolonar Were you actually out of the vegetables when you left last time? Perhaps you're running out of water, and can then make more when you come back due to more water.

Comment: @DCShannon. Yes, I'm usually out of Corn or Tato, since my farms mostly grow Mutfruits (of which I have over 100 by now). I have plenty of Purified Water too. Whenever I return to Sanctuary, I have about 10 or so Corn and Tato. It's possible that my crop only lands in my workshop inventory because I have a Scavenger Station, though.

Comment: @Nolonar That's interesting. That doesn't jive with my experiences. I guess it needs more testing.

Comment: From what I understand, the food that is automatically generated goes first to the settlers, then if there's any remaining it'll get deposited in the workshop.  What you need to do is A) have a balance of all the craftable foods growing in all settlements, B) harvest it manually (In my experience they regrow every time you fast travel), or C) do both.

Answer (score 5):

### Summary

There is *some* automatic harvesting, but it's inconsistent and less efficient than doing it manually.

**Some crops, including Corn and Mutfruit, will be automatically collected and placed in your workshop.** However, you can collect more crops from a single manual harvest of your plants than will show up in your workbench, and some crops, such as Tato, don't seem to be collected automatically.

It seems that you can do both, though. Going forward, lacking more tests, I will be keeping extra crops on a follower, and pulling any extra crops out of my workshop, in addition to manually harvesting.

---

### Notes on Tests

I think my tests may have been messed up by supply lines, and the fact that other settlements were relying on my test farm for food. A better, future test would be with one settlement not connected to others. If anyone conducts such a test before I get to it, please let me know.

I had about a dozen each of Tato, Mutfruit, and Corn planted in Sanctuary, near the default cooking station position. I completely cleared my workshop of any crops of any type, then slept for one hour at a time, checking the workshop after each hour, for three days. I found no plants in the workshop.

I then left town and came back the next day. I found four each of corn and mutfruit in my workshop, and zero tatos. Four is a lot less than a dozen. Other times I came back I found more or less, but never as many as there were crops planted. The fluctuating amount could have been impacted by fluctuating food needs in my other settlements.

It didn't seem to matter whether I had picked the crops myself recently or not, but once again I'm concerned that my supply lines may have been contaminating my test results.

If the supply lines are responsible for crops showing up or not, I'm surprised that it was my tatos that weren't being picked, as most of the other settlements have tatos planted. Maybe the tatos in their workshops were interfering, counting as crops in the workshop?

Clearly, more, better tests are needed to figure out all the parameters, but I've done enough to determine that at least *some* automatic harvesting occurs, but that it is not very efficient compared to picking the plants yourself. On the upside, it seems you can do both.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "automated" method of harvesting planted crops for replanting or to consume yourself.

You don't need to collect the food in order for your settlers to eat it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the settlers harvest the crop for you, but they also need to eat. If you have 5 settlers and 10 corn, they return zero to the workshop. They return the rest after they eat what they need. If you harvest yourself and use the production, they have nothing to eat and the colony satisfaction get down.

All settlers, including these connected to network eat first the tato. If you have 5 settlers in order to get tato production, you need a minimum of 11 tato plants.

Also Sanctuary seem bugged for unknow reason, and seem periodically need to be harvested manually.

It seem also that you have a food cap in workshop, after a certain amount of harvest, settlers stop storing food in workshop. You need to remove the food from the workshop and store them in another container.

Comment: I'm skeptical of your claim of settlers "eating". Obviously, just like with water, you're only eligible to harvest the excess but I doubt the settlers "eat" any of that.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Scavenging Station and assign a worker to it in each of the settlements you wish to collect excess scrap/food/water! You can find it under the resources > miscellaneous tab in workshop mode.

Comment: The scavenging station produces random resource.  This doesn't actually collect from your harvests.  See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242790/what-does-a-scavenging-station-do-and-how-do-i-use-it)