# How to assign people to tasks?

Tags: fallout-4

When I highlight a plant or guard post and it shows a red vault boy, does that mean it doesn't have an assigned person to it? I assigned someone to the post and it was green for a bit, then went back to red.

It seems to change colors from red to green and back no matter what I assign people to (Crops, guard posts, etc).  What does that mean?

Answer (score 7):

[As discussed here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242514/52800) - in order to assign a worker to a resource you must be in workshop mode and then approach the person you want to be the worker, speak to them and "command" them:

[image: command a villager]

...then go to the location you want them to work and you'll have the option to assign them to that post.

[image: select a resource object]

They'll then walk over from their original position and start working.

The person icon will go red again if you reassign a person who was already assigned to another task, or that person is currently not performing that task (ie: sleeping). [Unfortunately, there is no method of seeing an overview of all tasks your settlers are currently assigned to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242793/52800), however you can see what each individual is assigned to if you have visibility of that individual and their assigned task - this picture will show you what I mean:

[image: howcanyoutell]

This settler is only assigned to half of these carrots, another settler is doing the others, so when I target this settler is highlights half of the carrots.

Comment: I wish there was an easier way to monitor this stuff!!! Thanks!

Comment: I agree. It's not easy to monitor. I planted a bunch of crops and assigned people. When I returned, most crops were dead! Then when I plant new crops they have the green person icon suggesting someone has already been assigned to them? So confusing.